# Same route but different method in same controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make an approve and reject button on my web app in /events route. So what I am trying to achieve are :

- When user clicks "Approve", call EventController - registerEvent() method
- When user clicks "Reject", call EventController - rejectEvent() method

Here is my EventController :

```
public function approveEvent() {
    echo "Approve Event";
}

public function rejectEvent() {
    echo "Reject Event";
}

public function registerEvent() {
    echo "Register Event";
}
```

And this is where the button submit on /events blade view :

```
<form  action="{{ route('register.event') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ya</button>
</form>
```

Here are my routes :

```
Route::prefix('events')->group(function () {
     Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\EventController::class, 'index'])->name('event.index');
     Route::get('/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\EventController::class, 'show'])->name('event.details');
     Route::post('/', [App\Http\Controllers\EventController::class, 'registerEvent'])->name('register.event');
     Route::post('/', [App\Http\Controllers\EventController::class, 'approveEvent'])->name('approve.event');
     Route::post('/', [App\Http\Controllers\EventController::class, 'rejectEvent'])->name('reject.event');
});
```

Comment: you haven't shown any routes

Comment: You're right haha. I've edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear the goal. If you want to call different actions with the same button and form, you can paramtrize the form action considering the active state that you should have somewhere. Another solution is to call the same route with a different parameter.

Comment: do you have three buttons or just one button ?

Comment: just add the proper routes on the first parameter lile `post('/register')` `post('/approve')` `post('/reject')` easier to debug as well

Comment: You told us what you want, what is stopping you?  What is the problem? Does your code not work?  Errors?

Answer (score 0):

The last three routes definitions have the same url (/) and the same type (POST). This won’t work. You need to define different URL routes for each method (register/approve/reject). You can define one route for the three methods:

```
Route::post(‘event/{action}’, [EventController::class, ‘event’])->name(‘event.action’);
```

In the route, ‘action’ is the parameter to know which event was triggered. This parameter can be used in the controller with an if/else or switch condition.

Comment: So by this approach, I will have a method called event() (with parameters in the URL) in my EventController with if/else condition inside. Am I correct?